# For a complete file, how do I send the first word to the last?

Tags: ms-word, notepad++

For a complete file, how do I send the first word to the last?

e.g.,

```
void setABC(int a);
int setDEF(int b);
String setGEH(int b);
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me some shortcuts to change the above code as follows:

```
setABC(int a);void 
setDEF(int b);int
setGEH(int b); String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\w+)\h+(.+$)`
- Replace with: `$2$1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(\w+)       # group 1, 1 or more word characters
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(.+$)       # group 2, 1 or more any character until end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the hotkey or shortcut to this Sub, or assign this Sub to a button in MS Word to run.

```vb
Sub For_a_complete_file_how_do_I_send_the_first_word_to_the_last()
    Dim p As Paragraph, d As Document, rng As Range, ws As Word.Words, ur As UndoRecord
    Set d = ActiveDocument: Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "send_the_first_word_to_the_last"
    For Each p In d.Paragraphs
        If Not p.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            If Not p.Range.Information(wdInContentControl) And p.Range.Words.Count > 1 Then
                Set ws = p.Range.Words
                Set rng = ws(1)
                p.Range.Characters(p.Range.Characters.Count - 1).InsertAfter rng
                rng.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next p
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```